# Magento 2 payment module "this.item" is undefined

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods, payment

I tried to create my own custom payment module in Magento2.1.1 CE, and there is one thing I just can't figure out.

In many of the out-of-box modules, there is a property "**this.item**", for example `vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/banktransfer-method.js : line 22`, which were often used for `getTitle()` or `getCode()`, and the most importantly for `selectPaymentMethod()`.

However, "this.item" in my method renderer is always undefined, and I just can't find where & what I should do to assign it the desired value.

My js code is attached below:

```
define(
[
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
],
function (Component,rendererList) {
    'use strict';
    rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'pay2go',
                component: 'Logic_Pay2go/js/view/payment/method-renderer/pay2go-renderer'
    });
    return Component.extend({});
});
```

And the method renderer:

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
],
function ($, Component, quote, additionalValidators) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Logic_Pay2go/payment/pay2go'
        },
        redirectAfterPlaceOrder: false,

        afterPlaceOrder: function () {
            console.log(this.item); // Undefined.
            $.mage.redirect(window.checkoutConfig.payment.pay2go.redirectUrl);
        }
    });
});
```

The other behaviors were inherited from `Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default`.
Can any one please enlight me? Thanks.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize  `this._super()`

Like :

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
],
function ($, Component, quote, additionalValidators) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Logic_Pay2go/payment/pay2go'
    },
    initialize: function () {
            var self = this;
            this._super();

    },
    redirectAfterPlaceOrder: false,

    afterPlaceOrder: function () {
        console.log(this.item); // Undefined.
        $.mage.redirect(window.checkoutConfig.payment.pay2go.redirectUrl);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Ashish, it turns out that I wasn't writing `<module root>/etc/config.xml` correctly, in which "this.item" is being configured. Calling _super() here seems to make no difference, and many of the core payment modules didn't do so either. But still, thanks for providing your idea.